# How can I add a role and use apex managed sharing all at once?

Tags: sharing, dml, apex-managed-sharing

Question is in the title. For context, when a certain record is added, we would like to create a role (named after that record) and share it with that newly created role. Because of that, the flow ends up DML -> System DML -> DML. Since I would otherwise get a 'Mixed DML' error, that middle one needs to be separated with an @future. Unfortunately I need the third part of that to run in sequence but I cannot call one @future from another one. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Winter '15 you can use the Queueable interface to design an asynchronous job to be run, and which can kick off other asynchronous jobs.  [Original Salesforce Engineering Post on Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html)

Queueable in Winter '15 has a limited depth of 2 jobs, which should meet your needs if your initial record is created in real-time.  Otherwise Spring '15 is introducing infinite job-chaining if you can wait a couple weeks.

A word of caution for your Apex tests.  There is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XM1AAM) related to the use of System.enqueueJob() that causes most/all tests run afterwards to fail.  This sounds like it's addressed in Spring '15.  Also, the use of Queueable still counts against [the daily limits for asynchronous executions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#non_transactional_gov_limits_section_title).

Answer (score 3):

Do you need this in real-time ? Otherwise you could create an action table and a batch job that perform the last part.

Kind regards,

Rudy De Coninck

Comment: That is a possible route, however there is the chance that these objects could be inserted in quick succession but not in a batch, meaning I could spawn a large number of batch jobs in a short time. Could I come up against limits with this idea?